# Delphi Chromium enbedded alternative on Firemonkey OSX, Windows and Linux

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I need a fast and reliable HTML5 Browser component. For my needs TWebBrowser is too slow. I came across Chromium embedded but the components I found (DCEF3, DCEF4) are  relying on Windows units. Also, there are no libraries for OSX32 as chromium is only available on 64 Bit for Mac.

Is there an alternative approach for native HTML5 for FMX on Windows, Linux and OSX?

Background: I use Delphi, FMX and FMXLinux to create a cross platform application on Windows, OSX and Linux and would like to embed and deploy Chromium together with TMS Webcore to offer a fat client and web access simultaneously without having to develop complicated forms twice (FMX and Web).

Michael

Comment: Define "too slow"

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I run it on Raspberry pi 3 which runs Raspbian so know it good for Linux.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of DCEF maded by Salvador DF that can be compiled in Firemonkey at: https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi.
It is a library for Delphi that i have tested on Windows 32&64Bit with good results.

I need to try it on fmxLinux using the binaries that you can find at: http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html 
But i think there is some work to do.